# Ошибка в JSON, полученного из map editor

Tags: json, tile

Получаю  JSON карты  из Tiled Map Editor-а, но вместо цифр в поле data почему-то символ А. С чем это может быть связано? 
[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по схеме, в поле `data` хранится изображение в формате `base64`. Вставьте содержимое поле `data` в этот [онлайн декодер](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) – и нажмите «Generate Image». На выходе получится картинка, соответствующая тайлу. Картинки в формате `base64` не обязательно содержат цифры. Может быть вполне и строка, состоящая из одной буквы.